# Creating an unduplicated count of participants in a variety of activities

Tags: estimation, repeated-measures

I work for a nonprofit social service provider. We are attempting to create a count of participants of our services. We use a database that provides unduplicated numbers and demographics for a specific subset of participants. We also have three other (smaller databases) that provide us with names and some demographic information. We also have events and activities where we track our attendees by headcount, not name. Many of these attendees are already in our unduplicated subset, but others are not. We would like to provide an accurate number as possible of unduplicated participants. Is there a standard formula or format for calculating this number? Or based on our own information, can we create one that is feasible and can be explained in our reports? Thank you.

Comment: It's hard without having the names of the attendees. If you had those, then you could have just cross referenced that list with your unduplicated subset. What proportion of people do you think attended the events and are in the unduplicated subset? Are names a part of your unduplicated subset database? You could treat that proportion as the mean number of people who attended and are in the unduplicated subset.